# Im getting "an object reference is required for the non-static field" exception on non static methods... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a default page and an analisis page, and at Default I have some radio buttons to change a table, but I'm getting a "an object reference is required for the non-static field" exception on compilation, everything is non-static, and I haven't figured out why I'm getting this error.

Here's the code for _Default:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
    public bool Carro {
        get { return radCarroSi.Checked ;}
    }
}
```

And here is the code for Analisis:

```
public partial class Analisis : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
        _Default prevPage = PreviousPage as _Default;
            if (prevPage != null) {
                if (_Default.Carro == true) {
                    row8.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me? I believe its pretty easy but as I'm new at asp I haven't seen the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line of code are you getting the error on?

Comment: it was on the _Default.Carro == true one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have an instance of `_Default`:

You're just referring to the class name, not the instance of the class.

To elaborate a little further.

```
public class YourClass 
{
  public bool Carro { get; set; } 
}

YourClass instance = new YourClass();  // this would create a new instance of `YourClass`.
```

You can refer to it by using `instance.Carro` like you have done with `_Default.Carro`

However I believe you are trying to determine if the value of `Carro` has been checked in the page, `ASP.NET` doesn't work quite like this, you will need to understand how to manage state between the client and server.  This can be achieved via `ViewState, Session, Cookies and Query Strings`

Answer (score 0):

You can't check if a radio button is checked in a different page so this line will not work in the Analisis page (besides, you don't even have an instance of _Default):

```
    if (_Default.Carro == true) {
        row8.Visible = false;
    }
```

You need to pass the radion button value between pages using [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972338.aspx), [Querystring](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString) or some other method